# UglifyJsPlugin crashed Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I use webpack for build my app.

That's part of code:

```
if (isProd) {
    ...
    pluginsList.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
    ...
}
```

Error:

```
Unexpected closing tag "a" (" class="row align-center"> <a linkto=/ class="columns align-self-middle"> <img src=/icons/logo.png> [ERROR ->]</a> </div> </div> <lang-view class="columns medium-2 small-3 align-center"></lang-view> <div class=""): t@0:185
```

From template:

```
<div class="row align-center">
    <a linkTo="/" class="columns align-self-middle">
        <img src="/icons/logo.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

If I remove this plugin then everything work fine.

P.S. I use ngrx/router

Comment: What is linkto? Shouldn't it be href?

Comment: @PeterMorris it's ngrx/router

Comment: You are missing a closing / on <img src="....." />

Comment: @PeterMorris thanks but it's not fix problem

Comment: Shame. Update your question anyway, to stop others suggesting the same thing